# copy same records with Different ParentID from Existing ParentID

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to copy records from same Table. If `parentID` is null then I want to copy Parent and Child of that, with another `parentName`(I'll use replace Key word).
If it is not null then I want to copy that into same parent if same not exists in that parent only.

```
create table #Table(ID int primary key , Name varchar(10),ParentID int )

insert into #Table
select 1,'Suresh', -1
union
select 2,'Naresh', 1
union
select 3,'John', 1
union
select 4,'Kumar',3
union 
Select 5,'Dale John',3

select * from #Table

ID  Name    ParentID
-------------------
1   Suresh     -1
2   Naresh      1
3   John        1
4   Kumar       3
5   Dale John   3
```

1. if I select `ID = 1`, then all `ID` child should insert into same table if `Name not "Suresh"` and `ParentID not -1.`
2. If I select `ID = 3`, then `ID` 3 and Child should insert into same table if `Name and ParentID not John & 1`

Comment: Reddy how about showing some effort to solve your problem or alteast sample data and expected output

Comment: `INSERT INTO tblName select * from tblName where ParentId = @ParentId`

Comment: What do you mean by `copy`?

Comment: @ FutbolFan,
In my table Parent and Child relation is there. I want to copy(Insert into same table) the data into same table.
The process like, I can copy parent and all child into same table with rename if same parent name not exists.
I can copy child into same parent with different name name and name should not exists in that parent only.

Comment: Dear @Indian, I did not have example data. Hope you understand above text. If necessary, I will write something and post. Thank you.

Comment: Here is the problem Vagalla, we can't see your screen and don't really know what you are trying to do. You are asking for coding assistance but we don't know what your tables look like. Surely you have some table structures here and how can you not have some sample data? Even if you don't have any, make some up so we can help with the problem.

Comment: For one of the parent data like as below. 
EMPNO ENAME JOB                MGR
7698 BLAKE MANAGER 7839
7499 ALLEN SALESMAN 7698
7521 WARD SALESMAN 7698
7654 MARTIN SALESMAN 7698
7844 TURNER SALESMAN 7698
7900 JAMES CLERK         7698

If I select MGR = 7839 and with rename as new name, all will insert into same table. If rename and MGR same it should not insert.
If I Select any one child, that Child new name doesnot exists in same MGR.

Comment: @Sean Lange, thank you. Hope above content will give Idea.

Comment: No that doesn't actually clarify anything. It is a wall of gibberish that is impossible to tell what is what. You should take a look at this article for a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @Sean Lange, until I get more points in this blog, I am unable to post Tables , images Queries etc. Excuse me.

Comment: Actually the tables should be insert statements and there is nothing preventing you from adding text to your question. Another simple solution is to go to http://sqlfiddle.com/. You can create tables and sample data there.

Comment: Well apparently somebody edited the question and created the table and sample data. It still isn't clear what you are trying to do. And why do you have a ParentID of -1??? If there is no parent it should be NULL not some fake number.

Comment: can we make your parent ID as AutoIncrement

Comment: @tinka No, parent id is not AutoIncrement.

Answer (score 0):

Take those into Temp table and make the join between them.
IF not exists(---)
then insert into table.